# BigDecimal Multiplication

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I try to multiply two `BigDecimal` Values with `multiply` methods as follows,

```
BigDecimal dur = BigDecimal.valueOf(60/1.1);
BigDecimal bal = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.1);

BigDecimal ans  = dur.multiply(bal);

System.out.println("Ans:"+ans);
```

I am excepting ans as `60`. But i got it as,

```
Ans:59.999999999999994
```

Why this comming and how can we resolve it.

Comment: 60/1.1 doesn't have a finite decimal expansion, so can't be represented exactly as a BigDecimal...

Comment: Interestingly enough, the result using `double` is `60.0`...

Comment: @BoristheSpider a simpler example is `1.0 / 3 * 3` is `1.0` as a `double` but requires additional rounding when `BigDecimal` is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have a value which can't be represented in `double` but nor can it be represented in BigDecimal so you have to apply reasonable rounding to get the expected solution.

```
double d = 60 / 1.1 * 1.1;
System.out.println("double without rounding: " + d);
System.out.printf("double With rounding %.2f%n", d);

BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(60).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.1), 9, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.1));
System.out.println("BigDecimal without rounding: " + bd);
System.out.printf("BigDecimal with rounding %.2f%n", bd);
// or
bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println("BigDecimal with rounding: " + bd);
```

prints

```
double without rounding: 60.0
double With rounding 60.00
BigDecimal without rounding: 59.9999999995
BigDecimal with rounding 60.00
BigDecimal with rounding: 60.00
```

Note: `double` happens to round correctly for these values and gives the right answer. However, pick a different combination and it will be incorrect. e.g. `54.545454545454545 * 1.1 => 60.00000000000001`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `String` constructor instead of `double` one. `60/1.1` doesn't have `String` representation, as it is **54.(54)**.

`BigDecimal` does not support numbers that cannot be written as a fixed length decimals.

From `BigDecimal` Javadoc:

> In the case of divide, the exact quotient could have an infinitely long decimal expansion; for example, 1 divided by 3. If the quotient has a nonterminating decimal expansion and the operation is specified to return an exact result, an ArithmeticException is thrown. Otherwise, the exact result of the division is returned, as done for other operations.

Comment: While that would normally be the answer, in this case it's not going to help because while "1.1" is a fine string for the second `BigDecimal`, what would you use for the first?

Comment: Please see my edit: I've added info that `60/1.1` cannot be represented as `BigDecimal`.