# Multiply two numbers precisely in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I was searching for a precise way to multiply two floating point numbers in Java, and I read that I should use BigDecimal, however it doesn't work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(3.53);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(3.59);
BigDecimal c = a.multiply(b);

System.out.println(c);
```

Result:

```
12.672699999999998796873512674210388041622697702955394242845497954075284496866515837609767913818359375
```

Expected result:

```
12.6727
```

Comment: You should try printing `a` and `b`.

Comment: I see it is the same result, the expected result is some rounded value for the  above value, you can use something like **Math.round**

Comment: On the beginning float constants are not precisese. Must deep understand.

Comment: @Vanna Sorry for misleading you, I ddin't meant 12.6726(9), I just tried to keep it short

Comment: @JimGarrison: wrong duplicate. A proper duplicate would have Elliott's solution as its answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632454/new-bigdecimaldouble-vs-new-bigdecimalstring

Comment: Duplicate fixed.

Comment: Another duplicate would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899323/bigdecimal-multiplication)

Comment: @Mikemike another option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45663418/1057429

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks.  As I mentioned in a comment at the other answer, this comes up with clockwork regularity and has many duplicates on SO.  There's always [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use a [`BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) constructor it cannot be more precise than a `double`, use the `String` form instead. Like,

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("3.53");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("3.59");
BigDecimal c = a.multiply(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

Which outputs

```
12.6727
```

The linked Javadoc says in part -

> Notes:
>
> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new `BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates a `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a `double` (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> 2. The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing `new BigDecimal("0.1")` creates a BigDecimal which is *exactly* equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally recommended that the [String constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.lang.String-) be used in preference to this one.

Comment: How about using "BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(3.53d);" ?
That way I can use an actual double variable instead of converting it to String, and still retain precision

Comment: @Mikemike that's still a bad idea.  Using doubles in the first place is the problem.  Use String and BigDecimal without ever touching doubles in between.  If you use that approach with a number too precise for double, you'll still get wrong results.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Somehow I got right results:

    BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(3.53d);
    BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(3.59d);
    BigDecimal c = a.multiply(b);
  
    System.out.println(c); // 12.6727

Comment: I was very specific: a number too precise for double.  It won't go wrong soon, but it can go wrong if you have enough digits, and it's still a bad idea.

Comment: @Mikemike: Do not **convert** a double to a string. That would still have a big chance of getting the wrong values. **Start** right away with strings. Do not use doubles at all. If you use double, you may be lucky and get a reasonable result. But chances are you are not lucky. Double can represent some decimal values exactly, but not most of them.